# Transfer of photos from UbuntuOne to my computer

Tags: photo-management

How do I get photos from UbuntuOne storage to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable/sign into Ubuntu One and let it sync then your files should be available locally.
Then you can move them to where ever you wish.